# Get 2 consecutive rows of a resultset

Tags: java, sql, rows, resultset

I need to compare a row of a ResultSet with the consecutive row if the row string matches a particular string.

```
   while(rs.next())
    {
       String name = rs.getString("name");
     if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("SomeName")
      {
       String nextName =    //code to get the next consecutive row
        if(nextName.contains(name)
        {
         name = "NA";
         }

      }
     stringList.add(name);
     }
```

How can I get the next row while the cursor is still on that row?

Answer (score 2):

Approach hint: try storing the first one in a variable and then compare when reading the next row.

Really teaching you how to fish here, not handing you the catch.

Comment: Thanks but that may not work. As soon as I compare, I decide to either put the "name" in an arraylist or not. So adding the variable also occurs in the while loop. So I was looking to see if there is any method that can fetch both the current row value and the next row value in one shot.

Comment: @Raghu Sure that works. Store the previous record's value(s) in local variable(s) and compare in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh this out (a little):

```
String lastName = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    // do stuff with this row
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SomeName") && lastName != null) {
        // work with lastName & SomeName
    }

    // save/assign lastName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rs.next(), rs.getString() and then rs.previous() to move one row forward.

However a better option would be to memorize previous string value in a local variable and compare it at the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to store first row value then use another loop and compare that value.
Hint: use nested loop